# how to hide parameters in href link

Tags: jsp

On clicking **"View All Registered User"** Hyperlink the following URL is displayed in the Address field.

`http:/localhost:8080/RegSearch.jsp?primaryRegId=20001`

If I change the `primaryRegId` to *30909* instead of *20001* in the URL address and refresh the page it brings back the information of the other user *30909*, which is not secured.

I tried the post method also,but still we can see from the browser console.

Could you please let me know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "hide parameters in the link."  Any client-side parameters for any request can be spoofed like this.

What you do is validate the authorization for the requested data on the server.  So any user can still *request* any other user's data.  But in your server-side code for `RegSearch.jsp`, upon receiving that request, you would validate that the user making the request is *authorized* to see the data they're requesting.  If they are, show it to them.  If they're not, show them an error or redirect them to another page.

The security doesn't take place in the page which has the link on it.  The security takes place in the page which displays the data.